# Connecting 2 lists of nodes efficiently in java

Tags: java, graph-theory, max-flow

I'm building a flow network and I have two lists containing nodes which have properties associated with them. I have to connect both list based on these properties.

What I'm doing at the moment is iterate through list A and for each element iterate over all elements of list B and connect nodes if they have atleast 1 matching property. Which means I have to visit all nodes in list B once for every single element in list A.

Is there a faster way of connecting the two lists?

Maybe keep a matrix of all properties and just work through the column of a property and connect based on that? Would use up a lot more memory.

EDIT: for this problem both lists contain nodes which have a list of skills (say 1,2,3) i then need to connect nodes of list a to the same node of list b using that skill.

EDIT:
I now give the people a stack with skills and all jobs a hashset of skills needed. 
I then pop a skill and iterate over all jobs, if it contains a skill i connect both.

Comment: so each node has one property that is a list of items and a matching is based on having the exact same items, right ?

Comment: Yes, a person must have all skills associated with a job in order to be matched. But persons can have more skills. I guess polling a skill from a job and then start to iterate over persons calling a contains method on their set of skills could work, if true then poll next skill and so on. but still requires a lot of time

Comment: For every job I find the intersection with a member if its equal to requirements i connect else i go to the next member.
Still runs in O(nA*nB) though

Comment: with more space used (I don't know how many skills you have and how many space you can use to store pre-processed things) : you may compute one list for each skill, contaning the id of each candidate having this skill (you cound store all that into a HashMap<IdSkill, List<IdCandidate>>)
it takes O(nCandidates) to populate all those lists (only one iteration)

Then for every job, you take the candidates matching the first skill, filter the second skill's candidates list with them, etc. until the last skill and you get the list of all the candidates matching all the skills.

Comment: theoretically it's still O(nCandidates) for each job, but in real life you may take as "first" skill the skill with the least candidates, and iterate with the skills increasing the number of candidates so it would be less than O(nCandidates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without diving into the language, here are some thinking about algorithmics.

You could have some particular cases when you could improve this with a pre-processing of the lists, depending on your properties.

For example, let's assume your nodes have 2 properties : one id (int) and one weight, and you need to have a match on the id. Then as a pre-processing you could sort your two lists A and B based on your id

=> complexity : O(nA.log(nA)) + O(nB.log(nB))

After that you would do the matching between your 2 lists with 2 indexes and iterating each list only once. Assuming you sorted ascending on the id, at each step, you have `xA`, `iA`-th element of sorted list `sortA`, with id `idA`, and `xB`, `iB`-th element of sorted list `sortB`, with id `idB` and :

- if `idA = idB` there is a match, do `iA++` and `iB++`
- if `idA > idB` there is no match, do `iB++`
- if `idA < idB` there is no match, do `iA++`

=> complexity : O(nA + nB)

=> total complexity : O(nA + nB) + O(nA.log(nA)) + O(nB.log(nB)). Brute force complexity would be O(nA.nB)

You may find other ways to pre-process your lists based on your properties :

- Maybe you have a way to sort your lists, completely or partially?
- Maybe you could organize/store your properties or your checks with any useful tree-structure so that you improve your comparison workflow and will visit less nodes of list B for each one from list A?
- Maybe you could compute some hashcode-like property based on your properties so that you can match easily your checks for matching?
- Maybe you have any way to isolate already matched nodes (if it makes sense in your situation), to decrease list B's size?
- Maybe something else?

The key here is that if you split in multiple steps you may save time at the end thanks to additions instead of multiplications in your complexity

I hope it helps you

PS: in some cases you can also store more things and save time-complexity with an increased space-complexity. Thus you could pre-process multiple aspects of your lists but you would need to store more data -> your choice depends on your constraints also

---

Edit (integrates comments) :
With more space used (I don't know how many skills you have and how many space you can use to store pre-processed things) : you may compute one list for each skill, contaning the id of each candidate having this skill (you cound store all that into a HashMap>) it takes O(nCandidates) to populate all those lists (only one iteration).

For example you would have :

- skill1 : [candidate1, candidate2]
- skill2 : [candidate1, candidate3, candidate4, candidate5]
- skill3 : [candidate1, candidate2, candidate3, candidate5]
- skill4 : [candidate2, candidate3, candidate5]

Then for every job, you take the candidates matching the first skill, filter the second skill's candidates list with them, etc. until the last skill and you get the list of all the candidates matching all the skills.
Theoretically it's still O(nCandidates) for each job, but in "real life" you may take as first skill the skill with the least candidates, and iterate with the skills increasing the number of candidates so it would be less than O(nCandidates)

For example with previous list, and a job requiring skill1, skill3 and skill4, you would have :

- step : skill selected : candidates for this skill => remaining candidates
- step 1 : skill1 : [candidate1, candidate2] => [candidate1, candidate2]
- step 2 : skill4 : [candidate2, candidate3, candidate5] => [candidate2]
- step 3 : skill3 : [candidate1, candidate2, candidate3, candidate5] => [candidate2]

=> operations : looking for candidate1 and candidate2 in [candidate1, candidate2] + looking for candidate1 and candidate2 in [candidate2, candidate3, candidate5] + looking for candidate2 in [candidate2, candidate3, candidate5]

Same thing can be done in the reverse (candidate -> [skills]) to have the jobs matching the skills of a candidate

Comment: Updated problem description. 
This already helps a lot.
I have to connect a list of people with skills to a list of jobs with skill requirements. 

I now give the people a stack with skills and all jobs a hashset of skills needed. 
I then pop a skill and iterate over all jobs, if it contains a skill i connect both.

Comment: The problem is that any member and any job can have any set of skills which means pre-sorting wont really improve it as much, as you still have to check everything?
P.S. new here so tips on better communication are welcome